# Why is this lagrangian term a surface term?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, field-theory

I've seen certain models add the term $J^\mu\partial_\mu \phi$ to a Lagrangian, where $J^\mu$ is the current for a $U(1)$ global charge. They always claim that, if the current is conserved $\partial_\mu J^\mu=0$ then the term is actually a total derivative $\implies$ surface term and therefore unphysical.
The full theory could be, say,
$$ \mathcal{L} = i\bar{\psi}\partial_\mu \psi - m^2 \bar{\psi}\psi + q (\partial_\mu \phi) J^\mu, \quad \quad J^\mu = \bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu \psi,$$
Now, my way of understanding this term to be unphysical is that I can write the theory in a different field basis by rotating $\psi = e^{i q\phi} \psi'$, which gets rid of the extra term and bring us back to a free theory written in terms of $\psi'$ in this case.
On the other hand, I don't understand the 'surface term' argument. Consider:
$$\int dx^4 (\partial_\mu \phi) J^\mu = \int dx^4 [\partial_\mu ( \phi J^\mu) - \phi \;\partial_\mu J^\mu  ]$$
I think now people would tell me that, because the current is conserved, the second term is zero and we are left with a pure surface term. But $\partial_\mu J^\mu=0$ is only true for the classical solution once I have extremised the action. I can't say this is zero from the get go, can I?

Comment: Seen certain models where?

Comment: Mainly i have in mind spontaneous baryogenesis theories, which started from the original Cohen and Kaplan work 'Thermodynamic generation of the baryon asymmetry'

Comment: It depends on whether $J^\mu$ is external ( = fixed = background field), or internal ( = dynamical = integrated over).

Comment: I see what you mean. In this case $J^\mu$ is just shorthand for the $U(1)$ current $J^\mu = \bar{\psi} \gamma^\mu \psi$, so internal. $\phi$ is an external field.